# Google apps script connection problem with SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc, database-connection

I have a problem in Google apps script connecting to a SQL Server database. Here is the code:

```
//Function to connect to ms sql server

function conn_test_server(){
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:\\ipaddress\instance:port", 
"username", "password!");
}

//String formats i have used
//"jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress:port/database"
//"jdbc:sqlserver:\\ipaddress\instance:port"
```

When I tried it an error is thrown that tells my to check the connection string, username and password.

I have triple checked them, as well the port seems open as I can connect through another app and also have whitelist the required IP's so the firewall does not stop them to connecting.

Please, if you could tell me other things I can look into to solve this error I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think you might want to check [this open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119660771) on Google's Issue Tracker. Are you encountering the same issue?

Comment: Use the instance name, or the port, but not both. When you specify the instance name it needs to connect to the SQL Browser Service on the target server via udp/1434, which then resolves the instance name to a TCP port number that the client can use to connect with the SQL Server. If you already know the port number just use that, e.g.: `"jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress:port;databaseName=yourDatabaseNameHere"`